# evaluation about K-fold cross validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pytorch, k-fold

After K-fold cross validation, which evaluation metric was averaged?
Precision and recall, or F-measure?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`sklearn.model_selection.KFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) function is a utility that provides the folds but ***does not*** actually perform k-fold validation. You have to implement this yourself!

See documentation description:

> Provides train/test indices to split data in train/test sets. Split
> dataset into k consecutive folds (without shuffling by default).
>
> Each fold is then used once as a validation while the `k - 1` remaining
> folds form the training set.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. Can I ask that if I output Precision, Recall and F-measure for each round of K-fold validation, which metric should  I take average value?

Comment: Well, that's an open-ended question, you are asking me which metric to use to validate your network's performance...

Comment: yeah... not network, just some kind of BERT model.  And usually 3 metrics (Precision, Recall and F-measure)

Comment: Yes, that is what I said, there is no definite answer. It depends on your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, now I could make a decision. Much thanks